# Older sci-fi/fantasy book about a girl taken to another land by a group of males. They then have to fight through a jungle

Tags: story-identification, books

She starts to fall for the lead guy but gets separated from them before it can develop. Later, she joins with a guy who has a floating ship. He seemed awful, but ends up being a great guy and she falls for him. She finds out she is the daughter of a king-like person in one of the areas. She attends a festival with her father. I think there is a group of hive-like bee people that attack them, but I might be wrong about that. I also think there was more than one book.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: Also, where did the girl live before she was taken to another land? Did they take her through a portal to another reality, or did she always live in the same world as the other characters?

Comment: When you say "floating ship" it confuses me; floating on what?  (water, air, ether...)  Are there non-floating ships?

Comment: @DavidW - https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzkwOTg3ZmUtZjMyOC00ZTBkLTgzMDUtMzY3ZmUzOTg4NDYyL2ltYWdlL2ltYWdlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDAxOTExNTM@._V1_.jpg